# Can I leave Switzerland while awaiting work and residence permit?

Tags: visas, switzerland, multiple-entry, work-permit

I have Type D Visa stamped on my passport which is valid from 15-09-19 to 14-12-19 with multiple entries. I am moving to Geneva for work, possibly for 3 years. I have learnt that I will have to apply for a work and residence permit once I reach Geneva. However, for some personal reasons I wish to travel twice within 45 days after I move during which I might not have obtained my permits. I wished to know if I could travel to (1) Schengen countries, and, (2) back home to India before my permits come?

More specifically, does my type D visa which is valid for 3 months for multiple entries let me re-enter the country? Or do I need to apply for a fresh re-entry visa after I reach Geneva?

Also, since there is no passport control between Schengen countries, what stops me from leaving Switzerland and going into other Schengen countries like France, Spain and Germany?